# GitHub error on new repository

Tags: ssh, git, github, android-studio

I am using Github for the first time in android studio. I shared the project on github using import into version control but I am unable to see my files on the repository created. Please help

Android Studio event log error:

```
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Vampire@Vampire-PC.(none)')
 during executing git -c core.quotepath=false commit -m "Initial commit" --
5:15:30 PM Project is already on GitHub: GitHub
9:56:14 PM Project is already on GitHub: GitHub
10:11:46 PM Project is already on GitHub: GitHub
10:16:10 PM Project is already on GitHub: GitHub
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your e-mail address globally with ```git config youremailaddress@domain.suffix```?

Comment: yes I did that but still not working.

Comment: Hhmm, unusual. Is adding an RSA key and using that to upload with an acceptable workaround? Have you been able to try that? https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/